# Java decToHex in recursive - wrong output order

Tags: java, recursion, hex

I tried to check other questions close to this one, but couldn't figure out one answer for mine, that's why sending it as a new post. Hope this won't cause any problem.

I am trying to write a simple JAVA code for number conversion- from decimal to octal or hex. With octal everything is fine, but with hex, the output is in wrong order. like if the answer is 613 - program gives out 316.

Here is my full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cem {
    public static void octalconverter(int a) {
        if (a == 0) { //our base
            System.out.println(); //I first put here return a, but then it was adding zeros to the end
        } else {
            System.out.print(a % 8);// first remainder = last digit, and so on
            octalconverter(a / 8); //recursively going till it is base
        }
    }

    public static void hexconverter(int a) {

        if (a == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        } else {

            System.out.print(hexchart(a % 16));
            hexconverter(a / 16);
        }
    }

    public static String hexchart(int a) {
        String result = "";
        if (a <= 9) {
            result = a + result;
        } else {
            if (a == 10)
                result = result + "A";
            // System.out.print("A");
            if (a == 11)
                result = result + "B";
            // System.out.print("B");
            if (a == 12)
                result = result + "C";
            // System.out.print("C");
            if (a == 13)
                result = result + "D";
            //System.out.print("D");
            if (a == 14)
                result = result + "E";
            //System.out.print("E");
            if (a == 15)
                result = result + "F";
            // System.out.print("F");
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner oScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your decimal number : "); //getting input
        int num = oScan.nextInt(); //assigning
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Octal Base Conversion   ####  Enter 2 for Hex Conversion");
        int num2 = oScan.nextInt();

        if (num2 == 1) {
            System.out.print(num + " in Octal(base8) system is : ");
            octalconverter(num); //conversion
        } else if (num2 == 2) {
            System.out.print(num + " in Hexadecimal(base16) system is : ");
            hexconverter(num);
        } else {
            System.out.println("You entered a wrong choice for conversion type, please restart the program");
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me where I messed up. I also must say I am looking for the mistake I did here, not another way of how to write this code. Thank you those who are willing to share another way of it, but again I need to learn my mistake here. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Both octal and hex converters are wrong, since you print "last" digit *before* recursive call to print "earlier" digits. Move `print()` to after the recursive call.

Comment: I ran your code and output was: `613 in Hexadecimal(base16) system is : 562`.

Comment: hey Andreas, :) thanks for helping out again. But, Octal gives the correct output. also you mean for hexconverter to put the print() after hexconverter(a/16) ??

Comment: exactly DimaSan, although the answer is 265 for 613, it prints out in wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public static void hexconverter(int a) {
    if (a == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.print(hexchart(a % 16));
        hexconverter(a / 16);
    }
}
```

To

```
public static void hexconverter(int a) {
    if (a == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        hexconverter(a / 16);
        System.out.print(hexchart(a % 16));
    }
}
```

Your octal conversion is also not working properly. It prints in reverse order. So just swapped those instructions also.

Comment: When I tried this, it does not print out anything. are you sure?

Comment: Oh yes, so sorry user2509521, it was in the next line, here is the output:

Comment: run:
Please enter your decimal number : 
613
Enter 1 for Octal Base Conversion   ####  Enter 2 for Hex Conversion
2
613 in Hexadecimal(base16) system is : 
265BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)

Comment: Yes, I did that. Thank you very much again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Bill Gates once said that he would always "hire a lazy person to do a difficult job" at Microsoft. ... "Because a lazy person will find an easy way to do it."

I know you said you aren't looking for another way of how to write this code but this is much easier way to get the job done.

---

```
public static String octalNumber = "";

public static void octalconverter(int a){

   while(a!=0){
       octalNumber = octalNumber + String.valueOf(a%8);
       a = a/8;
   }
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder(octalNumber).reverse().toString());

}
```

---

Final number has to be reversed.That was a mistake.

Comment: Pocho, you are right, but I am only allowed to use recursives, and while is a iteration that I cannot use. :) But, yeah, if there weren't lazy people, we all would be still walking, somebody in the history was too lazy to walk, and that's why he invented the car, most probably another somebody(or somebodies) was too lazy to use the car, that's why they invented the plane. Let's hope another lazy person comes soon so we get teleportation :)